# Execute tcsh script from bash and keep tcsh session interactive

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, tcsh, subshell

I have tcsh script (as shown below), which I want to execute in csh from the bash shell, and want to maintain the tcsh session at the end of the file.

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv var1 value1
set var2 value2
# ----- some code -----
```

I would like to have something as follows

```
bash-> csh abovescript.sh
. . . . . output .. . . . 

tcsh-> echo $var2 
value2
tcsh-> exit
bash-> echo "back to bash session"
```

what is the best way to do this? It can be easily done if I am calling bash script from tcsh using `bash --init-file script.sh`, but I am not able to find an equivalent option in tcsh.

**Note**
adding `csh` command at the end of the file launches a new shell session (without the current variables), that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The best way would probably be to re-write the script in `bash`. `(t)csh` is notorious for being unsuitable for scripting anyway.

Comment: I agree but there are some tools that are hardcoded in tcsh, and I don't have any other option than using tcsh. The whole idea of the above exercise is to use bash as much as possible and invoke tcsh as required

Comment: you wrote *"command at the end of the file launches a new shell session (without the current variables)"* . Any variables you export from `bash` should be available in any child processes, including another (and different) shell. Good luck.

Comment: How set the variables in your script? The `setenv` exports variables into child shell (works for me). Or could you provide this script (or its part)?

Comment: @uzsolt `set` does not export, though. Presumably that's the reason an interactive `tcsh` is required, though it's not clear what "tools" prevent using `bash` for everything instead.

Comment: `setenv` is the (t)csh version of `export` found in (almost) all other shells. You can list multiple var names on one cmd line, like `export v1 v2 v3 ... vN`., or you can do `export myVar=someValue` when you set the value for `myVar`. So you can have `v1=someOthervalue; ..... other code ; export v1 v2 ...` where the `export` happens later (just before you call your `tcsh` script, for instance).Good luck.

Comment: @chepner these are some EDA tools from Synopsys and Cadence, for the legacy reason they still ship projects with csh scripts, and most they are executed in RedHat Linux.

Comment: I am curious though, why simple bash option like `bash --init-file script.sh` is not available for tcsh. actually that solves my problem in bash.

Comment: @shellter agree `setenv` does the job, but the part where I have written `- - - - - - some code - - - - ` I am sourcing/executing some vendors script which is mot editable (rather I don't want to modify them as they are tested ok), so at the end of the script I want interaction session with the same environment.

Comment: @GaneshGore This may be a job for `expect`: have it start the interactive `tcsh` session, then send `source abovescript.csh` before returning control to you.

Comment: Not sure if you can make a wrapper script that just includes `export v1 v2 ... vN` and then expect the `v1=value` form to inherit the `export` for itself and any child programs. Seems possible and easy to test. Let us know what you find out ;-) Good luck!